# Unable to find element with Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find out the xpath for resource manager element, when I tried with this code, 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("Resource Manager xpath")).click()`, I turned up with error saying unable to find the element.

```
<div class="os-titlebar navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav menu-primary os-navbar-icon">
          <ul class="nav context-menu" style="">
           <ul class="nav os-navbar-icon os-titlebar-shortcuts pull-right os_shortcuts">
                 <li class="os-navbar-icon-home selected">
                 <li class="os-navbar-icon-quicklaunch os_quick_start">
                 <li class="os-navbar-icon-resourcemanager">
                  <li class="os-navbar-icon-apptray">
                  <li class="os-navbar-icon-notifications">
                  <li class="os-navbar-icon-minimise-close">
            </ul>
<form class="navbar-search pull-right ui-os-search-form" action="">
<ul class="nav os-navbar-icon os-desktop-navigation" style="left: 407.5px;">
</div>
```

Comment: can you please mention what actual xpath you used?

Comment: Oops... I didn't looked at answers. They must have helped you.

Answer (score 3):

`Resource Manager xpath` is not a valid xpath expression.

This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='os-navbar-icon-resourcemanager']")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, when i use the code i'm not getting any error, but the element is not getting clicked.... :(

Comment: @ShivaChalla, then that's a different question.

Comment: @Arran: The Scenario is i want to click on the resource manager element, where all the elements are injected with Java script, while page loading all the elements that i mentioned in the above code are injected. For this when i used the findElement with xpath, it is failing to find the element. Please let me know if you are not clear...

Comment: You need to wait for the elements to appear.

Comment: @ShivaChalla look into WebDriverWait

Comment: Also since this question answered your problem you should mark it as correct and upvote it.  There seem to be more and more people not accepting correct answers or upvoting when Selenium questions are answered.  It's very bad form

Comment: You should 1)Click the Up arrow next to this answer 2) mark this answer as the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use css selector instead of xpath. Also an example of [WebDriverWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,300/*timeout in seconds*/);
By findBy = By.cssSelector("li.os-navbar-icon-resourcemanager");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(findBy)).click();
```

Comment: a better wait example would be to wait for that specific element to click on

Comment: @Alp I do if you notice the wait.until(). It waits until the element is ready to click and THEN it clicks.

Answer (score 1):

you may face "Unable to find element" only in two case for sure.

```
 1.The Element is yet to Load
     - Put some wait here.
 2. You may try to locate the element wrongly .
     - Double Check your Xpath/ID(what ever)
     - Make sure you are in the same frame where the element is present.If not, switch to the frame then.
```